/wp-content pages in Wordpress are being indexed as its own page
I'm getting dozens of unwanted indexed pages in Wordpress that are actually media files URLs like this one:
/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/Ellipse-78
I added a rule in my robots.txt, but I'm not sure it's okay because I do want crawlers to track my favicon.
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/
What should I do?
Thank you all

Indexing means you can find your favicon when searching using Google image. I guess what you want is having your favicon alongside your website name in search results.
Just having the correct HTML pointing to the favicon is fine:
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

Or you could have the default favicon.ico in your root path. So even if you disallow /wp-content/uploads/ your favicon should appear in Google results.

You can use plugins such as Yoast SEO or Prevent Direct Access (PDA) to precisely control what should be indexed and what shouldn't be.
Solutions mentioned in this article could be useful in your case - https://woorkup.com/wordpress-image-attachment-page/
